# Coping database file in Windows Corona Simulator: Database disk image is malformed

Tags: sqlite, coronasdk

In my Corona SDK app I'm coping a sqlite database file to another location and then opening it.
It works fine in Corona Simulator on Mac OS as well as in Android build. But it doesn't work in Corona Simulator on Windows 8. The error message I have after a first database operation is  "database disk image is malformed".

I found a problem description on Corona site 
http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2011/07/09/sqlite-db-being-corrupted-windows

Does anybody know a solution for this issue?

Comment: After following the link and reading the responsive, I would have to ask you how you are copying the file?  Are you opening it in binary mode?  

The solution there should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would post the answer, even though this was posted a while back for future searchers:

Windows is picky when copying the file for the simulator.  It requires that you specify that the database is going to be read and written as a binary file:

```
local fileSource = io.open( pathSource, "rb" ) 
local fileDest = io.open( pathDest, "wb" )
```

While it works fine in the Mac Corona Simulator without specifying the binary read/write, it is required for Windows development.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the actual problem with the code on the link (besides the already mentioned by Dr. Brian Burton) is that they are not closing the initial opened file in case is not null. So instead of:

```
if( file == nil )then
     -- Doesn't Already Exist, So Copy it In From Resource Directory
    pathSource = system.pathForFile( dbName, system.ResourceDirectory )
    fileSource = io.open( pathSource, "r" )
    contentsSource = fileSource:read( "*a" )

    -- Write Destination File in Documents Directory
    pathDest = system.pathForFile( dbName, system.DocumentsDirectory )
    fileDest = io.open( pathDest, "w" )
    fileDest:write( contentsSource )

    -- Done
    io.close( fileSource )
    io.close( fileDest )
end
```

you should add and ELSE clause at the end, like this:

```
if( file == nil )then
     -- Doesn't Already Exist, So Copy it In From Resource Directory
    pathSource = system.pathForFile( dbName, system.ResourceDirectory )
    fileSource = io.open( pathSource, "rb" )
    contentsSource = fileSource:read( "*a" )

    -- Write Destination File in Documents Directory
    pathDest = system.pathForFile( dbName, system.DocumentsDirectory )
    fileDest = io.open( pathDest, "wb" )
    fileDest:write( contentsSource )

    -- Doneb
    io.close( fileSource )
    io.close( fileDest )
else
    io.close(file)
end
```

Cheers!